# Android - full screen button makes youtube video (youtube embed) in webView crash

Tags: android, html, webview, youtube

this is my xml structure (dynamically changes. code generated)

```
<LinearLayout>
    <WebView></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

on that webView, i set this html code

```
<html><body><iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" height="100%" width="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vS6mwyHNacA?rel=0&html5=1" frameborder="0"></iframe></body></html>
```

It plays alright when i press play button. but when i press full screen button (bottom right corner) the video stops playing. after that, the video just won't play even when i press the play button again or drag the progress bar.

can anybody tell me how to make the full screen button works?

this is the logcat

```
10-24 09:28:42.065: V/MediaPlayer(25419): isPlaying: 1
10-24 09:28:42.065: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25419): isPlaying: 1
10-24 09:28:42.125: V/MediaPlayer(25419): isPlaying: 1
10-24 09:28:42.125: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25419): isPlaying: 1
10-24 09:28:42.225: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(25419): enterFullScreenVideo() called.
10-24 09:28:42.225: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25419): getCurrentPosition: 9583 (msec)
10-24 09:28:42.225: V/MediaPlayer(25419): isPlaying: 1
10-24 09:28:42.225: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25419): isPlaying: 1
10-24 09:28:42.230: V/MediaPlayer(25419): isPlaying: 1
10-24 09:28:42.230: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25419): isPlaying: 1
10-24 09:28:42.230: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25419): pause
10-24 09:28:42.230: V/MediaPlayer(25419): pause
10-24 09:28:42.230: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25419): release
10-24 09:28:42.230: V/MediaPlayer(25419): setListener
10-24 09:28:42.230: V/MediaPlayer(25419): disconnect
10-24 09:28:42.275: V/MediaPlayer(25419): destructor
10-24 09:28:42.275: V/MediaPlayer(25419): disconnect
10-24 09:28:42.275: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(25419): enterFullScreenVideo : mHTML5VideoView.release()
10-24 09:28:42.275: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(25419): native_setup
10-24 09:28:42.275: V/MediaPlayer(25419): constructor
10-24 09:28:42.275: V/MediaPlayer(25419): setListener
10-24 09:28:50.450: V/webview(25419): NO_FAST_DRAW = false
10-24 09:28:50.560: V/webview(25419):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
10-24 09:28:50.975: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(25419): handleMessage : SEEK
10-24 09:28:50.975: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(25419): play() : videoView not ready
10-24 09:28:58.355: V/webview(25419): NO_FAST_DRAW = false
10-24 09:28:58.465: V/webview(25419):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
10-24 09:29:04.105: V/webview(25419): NO_FAST_DRAW = false
10-24 09:29:04.195: V/webview(25419):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport  FASLE 
10-24 09:29:04.590: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(25419): handleMessage : PAUSE
10-24 09:29:04.590: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(25419): handleMessage : SEEK
10-24 09:29:04.590: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(25419): handleMessage : SEEK
10-24 09:29:04.590: D/HTML5VideoViewProxy(25419): play() : videoView not ready
```

"enterFullScreenVideo() called" is when I press the full screen button

the video just pauses after that

"play() : videoView not ready" is when I press the play button

the video still won't play again

Comment: Please post full error logcat.

Comment: see my edit
i post the error logcat

Comment: I'm seeing exactly this behaviour with a Samsung Note 2 running Android 4.1.1, in my own app which displays a youtube page in its own WebView. Did you ever find a fix?